# How to make the 'less' command handle UTF-8?

Tags: mac-osx, terminal, utf-8, unicode

On my Mac terminal, printing UTF-8 works in general, but the `less` doesn't work correctly.

So this works correctly:

```
$  echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'   
€
```

but piping it into less gives something like this:

```
$  echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac' | less  
<E2><82><AC>
```

How can this be fixed?

For diagnostics:

I'm using Mac OS 10.6.8. less version 418, Terminal 2.1.2 (273.1).

The output of my locale is this:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL="C"
```

Answer (score 60):

Okay, I found the answer after some googling. Apparently, `LESSCHARSET` needs to be set like this:

```
export LESSCHARSET=utf-8
```

Now `less` works fine for me.

Comment: I had the same problem on CentOS. This line also fixed it there.

Comment: For me what solved the problem was using `less -r` (display "raw" control characters)

Comment: This works in Debian 8 too, thanks!

Comment: `less -r` does the same thing but also handles emojis correctly, which `export LESSCHARSET=utf-8` does not.

Answer (score 6):

If you can see some unicode characters in `less`, but are unable to get `less` to display emoji, try upgrading `less` to a more recent version. On Mac OS X, I went from version 458 to 481 and that fixed my problem (for example, `git log` can now display emoji in commit messages).

If you have homebrew, you can replace the system less with a newer version by running `brew install homebrew/dupes/less`.

Comment: Thanks! With newer versions of homebrew, you just need to `brew install less` to get the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me with

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: LC_CTYPE is the important one. However the rules less uses are bizarre: instead of retrieving the encoding from the locale, it looks for the string "utf-8" (or a few other possibilities) in its name.So you’ll need to use LESSCHARSET if you want some other encoding or if your locale name doesn’t match less’s preconceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I googled this and tried the following environment variables which worked for me:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_us.UTF-8
```

Seeing as I find the LC_ALL in multiple different answers I think this is the correct one. But maybe not the only right answer, there could of course be more correct answers to this question.

Anyway some more googling gave me this description for the variable:

> LC_ALL 
>   This variable determines the values for all locale categories.
>   The value of the LC_ALL environment variable has precedence over any
>   of the other environment variables starting with LC_ (LC_COLLATE,
>   LC_CTYPE, LC_MESSAGES, LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME) and the LANG
>   environment variable.

source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/envvar.html

Leading me to think this is the language variable to rule them all :)

Comment: Please feel free to post `less`' version number.

Comment: sure, less 458 (GNU regular expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Just update you `[less][1]`

Do it with brew.

```
brew install homebrew/core/less
```