# How to set LESSCHARSET system wide?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, environment-variables, less

This is a follow up on [How to make the 'less' command handle UTF-8?](https://serverfault.com/questions/414760/how-to-make-the-less-command-handle-utf-8)

If I want to set options for `less` globally, so that each user doesn't have to fiddle with their own env vars (`.basrc`, etc) individually, where should it be set?

`/etc/bashrc` is not a good option as then I'd have to set one up for each shell.

The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/less.1.html) for `less` mention a `lesskey` file that has a `#env` section where i can set this, but there is no mention of where to put it. It does mention that I can use env vars `LESSKEY_SYSTEM` and `LESSKEY` to point to the file... but that creates a chicken vs egg problem.

Other distros man pages mention `/usr/local/etc/sysless` but that is not used on ubuntu from my tests.

Answer (score 2):

`strace` to the rescue.

```
open("/usr/bin/.sysless", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/sysless", O_RDONLY)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/user/.less", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/user/.lesshst", O_RDONLY)   = 3
```

`/usr/bin/.sysless` is very odd. let's skip that. `/etc/sysless` sounds more sane. I think this is the answer. I can't say for sure because now less gives me

> Cannot use lesskey file "/etc/sysless"

Still need to debug that since the contents of that file for now are copied from the man page...

Comment: The lesskey file (binary) needs to be build with lesskey(1) command. Assuming you saved your text input file as `~/.lesskey` you can install it system-wide with `lesskey -o /etc/sysless`